# Can't reach if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, random

Hello I am writing a program in C# that takes a number and asks the user for a number, once the user enters the number the program checks if it matches the original number, if not it is supposed to tell the user if their answer was less or greater than, however my if statement is not working.

```
        //Boolean if user passes
        Boolean Userpassed;
        // Declares Answer Variable
        int answer = 6;
        // Asks user for a number
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
        // Displays Message
        Console.ReadLine();
        // Takes User Input as String
        string useranswer = Console.ReadLine();
        // Declares integer for actual integer
        int userinput;
        // User string parsed to Int
        userinput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        // Displays Message
        Console.ReadLine();
        // Checks if input is equal to answer
        if (userinput == answer)
        {
            // User passes
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, you have passed");

        }
        // Checks if input is greater than answer
        else if (userinput > answer)
        {
            // User Fails
            Console.WriteLine("The actual answer is less than what you entered");
        }
        // Checks if input is less than answer
        else if (userinput < answer)
        {
            // User Fails
            Console.WriteLine("The actual answer is greater than what you entered");
        }
        // Displays Message
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The first if statement does not work as when I enter 6 it simply passes to the else loop. Then if I enter a different number it does not get past the second else loop. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Why aren't you converting `useranswer` to  `userinput`?  Also `Console.Read` isn't going to return what you think it does.  And you have way to many `ReadLine`s.  The user has to hit enter 3 time before you get to the `if`.

Comment: @juharr when I convert useranswer it says I cannot convert string to integer

Comment: @ProTalz `int user input = Int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` `TryParse` is better but too long for a comment

Comment: `userinput = Convert.ToInt32(useranswer)` doesn't work?  What error do you get?  Note that if you just use `Console.Read` and press the 6 key it will not return 6, it will return 54 the Ascii value of the character 6.

Comment: It seems you are confused about the meaning of `Console.Read` and `Console.ReadLine`. [`Console.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=netframework-4.7.2) reads and returns one character from the console. [`Console.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline) reads a line of characters (until the user presses enter) and returns them as a string. Just use something like this: `var userinput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` to read an integer from standard input.

Comment: @matt juharr jeroenh thanks for the help I got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are entering more `Console.ReadLine();` than you need

By Without making more changes in your code

```
 // Boolean if user passes
 Boolean Userpassed;
 // Declares Answer Variable
 int answer = 6;
 // Asks user for a number
 Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
 // Displays Message
 // Console.ReadLine();       <== Remove this line
 // Takes User Input as String
 string useranswer = Console.ReadLine();
 // Declares integer for actual integer
 int userinput;
 // User string parsed to Int
 userinput = Convert.ToInt32(useranswer);       //<== pass useranswer to here
 // Displays Message
 // Console.ReadLine();    <== Remove this line
 // Checks if input is equal to answer

 //your rest code is same here
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry u will learn these things

```
int ans = 6;
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
//taking integer input from user
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
//now checking user input with selected answere
if(ans == input)//true, when user predicts correct number
{
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations!!!");
}
else if(input < ans)//true, when user predicted number < actual number
{
    Console.WriteLine("The actual answer is less than what you entered");
}
else//true, when both above conditions are false
{
    Console.WriteLine("The actual answer is greater than what you entered");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `Parse` input *line* not `Convert` a *single char*, i.e. instead of

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10");
 // Displays Message
 // Console.ReadLine();       <== Remove this line
 // Takes User Input as String
 string useranswer = Console.ReadLine();
 // Declares integer for actual integer
 int userinput;
 // User string parsed to Int
 userinput = Convert.ToInt32(useranswer);
```

you should put something like this:

```
 int userinput = 0;

 // Keep on asking until valid input provided - an integer number in [1..10] range
 while (true) {
   Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 10");

   if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userinput))
     Console.WriteLine("Sorry, syntax error; try again");
   else if (userinput < 0)
     Console.WriteLine("Your input less than 0; try again");  
   else if (userinput > 10)
     Console.WriteLine("Your input greater than 10; try again");  
   else
     break; // <- Valid input
 }
```